# Missing Datasource Configuration when run cakephp project in live

Tags: cakephp

Showing error when run project in live server.error as been below

> Missing Datasource Configuration Error: 
>   The datasource configuration
>   default was not found in database.php.

my database.php file

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default;
        function __construct(){
            $this->default = array(
                'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                'persistent' => false,
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'login' => 'root',
                'password' => 'xxxxxx',
                'database' => 'demo',
                'prefix' => '',
            );
        }
  }
```

please help me to resolve that issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code :

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'your_db_name',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'test_database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

}

change in first db configuration only do not change in $test configuration. Leave as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I got a default equal to this, see if it helps

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'tutorial',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```